# Modeling transitions into and out of poverty

Tags: panel-data, logit

I have individual panel data for two consecutive years, my variable of interest is "being under/over a monetary threshold", which is the poverty level. More precisely, I am interested in analyzing the dynamics of poverty, that is people that stay poor, people that stay non poor, and people that transistion between the two states.

I have 'a lot' of potential explicative variables : it is the French version of [SILC](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/microdata/european_union_statistics_on_income_and_living_conditions), so I have access to age, gender, job status and job if employed, education, family composition, subjective well-being, material deprivation, income, taxes, some transfers....

My first descriptive statistics are to examine the proportion of people in and out of poverty for various subpopulation for both years.

Then, my idea would be to do a logistic regression, and eventually to use odds ratios.

I then have two questions :

- Is this analysis valid ?
- Is there a better way to obtain results about my problematic ?

Comment: It is impossible to opine on the validity of "a logistic regression" without knowing the details. What would the independent and dependent variables be?

Comment: I added some examples of dependent variables, for my independent variable I am less sure, I can run one regression with the independent variable being (being poor in N or not) and adding (being poor or not in N-1) as a dependent variable.

Moreover my question is also is there a bette way than a logistic regression, as i do not really utilize the panel dimension, but just uses the 'being poor' at two different times as two different variables